# Schwarzschild black hole and two particles

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems, event-horizon, geodesics

*I'm looking to solve a problem using general relativity theory to "get a taste" of it. I've little knowledge of the the theory so just want to "taste" it before diving deep into existing courses Hence a solution would be much appreciated! This is not a homework of any sorts.*

Let's say we have a super-massive Schwarzschild black hole of radius $R$ and mass $M$.

Let's say at certain moment of time there is a system of two non-interacting particles located exactly on the same line with the black hole's center. We know the space-time distance between the particles. Both particles are of a negligible mass (say neutrons) and initially are located at distance $D>R$ from the black hole center. Both of them are free falling straight toward the center of the black hole.

Now, according to Schwarzschild model at the even horizon one space-like coordinate (radial direction) and one time-like coordinate (time in "outer world") are "swapping".

How the coordinates of the two particles could be described in their local reference frame as they falling through the event horizon and beyond? How's the space-time distance between these two particles would change over their local time?

I've tried to get through the Schwarzschild metric, but without a prior experience I just feel I'm missing some known simple approach.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that a Schwarzschild black hole is completely specified by its mass, meaning the radius is fixed once the mass is fixed. More precisely, for a Schwarzschild black hole of mass $M$, the radius will be given by $R = 2GM$ (units with $c=1$).

Comment: What do you mean by *spacetime distance between these two particles*? Do you mean the round-trip time for a light signal to travel from particle A to particle B and then back to particle A again, as measured by particle A's internal clock?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly yes, that's what I mean.